# Plot least-squares means for groups of factor levels

Tags: r, plot, lme4, mixed-models, lsmeans

I'm looking for a simple way to extract (and plot) the least-squares means of specified combinations of levels of one factor, for each level of another factor.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
model.data <- data.frame(time = factor(paste0("day", rep(1:8, each = 16))),
  animal = factor(rep(1:16, each = 8)),
  tissue = factor(c("blood", "liver", "kidney", "brain")),
  value = runif(128)
  )
```

Setting up custom contrasts for factor "time":

```
library("phia")
custom.contrasts <- as.data.frame(contrastCoefficients(
   time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3 - (day4+day5+day6)/3,
   time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3 - (day7+day8)/2,
   time ~ (day4+day5+day6)/3 - (day7+day8)/2,
   data = model.data, normalize = FALSE))

colnames(custom.contrasts) <- c("early - late",
  "early - very late",
  "late  - very late")

custom.contrasts.lsmc <- function(...) return(custom.contrasts)
```

Fitting the model and calculating the least-squares means:

```
library("lme4")
tissue.model <- lmer(value ~ time * tissue + (1|animal), model.data)
library("lsmeans")
tissue.lsm <- lsmeans(tissue.model, custom.contrasts ~ time | tissue)
```

Plotting:

```
plot(tissue.lsm$lsmeans)
dev.new()
plot(tissue.lsm$contrasts)
```

Now, the second plot has the combinations that I want, but it shows the difference between the combined means, rather than the means themselves.

I can get the individual values from `tissue.lsm$lsmeans` and calculate the combined means myself, but I have the nagging feeling that there is an easier way that I just don't see. All the data should be in the `lsmobj`, after all.

```
early.mean.liver = mean(model.data$value[model.data$tissue == "liver" & 
  model.data$time %in% c("day1", "day2", "day3")])
late.mean.liver = mean(model.data$value[model.data$tissue == "liver" & 
  model.data$time %in% c("day4", "day5", "day6")])
vlate.mean.liver = mean(model.data$value[model.data$tissue == "liver" & 
  model.data$time %in% c("day7", "day8")])
# ... for each level of "tissue"


#compare to tissue.lsm$contrasts
early.mean.liver - late.mean.liver 
early.mean.liver - vlate.mean.liver
late.mean.liver - vlate.mean.liver
```

I'm looking forward to hearing your comments or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just create a second coefficients matrix to get the combined means of interest for each tissue?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @aosmith! I don't know how to do that, though - can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to calculate the contrast coefficients for the group means of interest in addition to the contrast coefficients for the differences in group means that you calculated in `custom_contrasts`.  For example, you could do this separately as `custom.contrasts2`.

```
custom.contrasts2 <- as.data.frame(contrastCoefficients(
    time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3,
    time ~ (day4+day5+day6)/3,
    time ~ (day7+day8)/2,
    data = model.data, normalize = FALSE))

colnames(custom.contrasts2) <- c("early",
                          "late",
                          "very late")

custom.contrasts2.lsmc <- function(...) return(custom.contrasts2)

lsmeans(tissue.model, custom.contrasts2 ~ time | tissue)$contrasts
```

Here are just the outputs for `liver`, which are the group means you are after.

```
...
 tissue = liver:
 contrast    estimate         SE   df t.ratio p.value
 early      0.4481244 0.07902715 70.4   5.671  <.0001
 late       0.4618041 0.07902715 70.4   5.844  <.0001
 lvery late 0.3824247 0.09678810 70.4   3.951  0.0002
```

If you know you want both the group means and differences in group means, you can just add to the contrast coefficients matrix you create via`contrastCoefficients`.

```
custom.contrasts <- as.data.frame(contrastCoefficients(
    time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3,
    time ~ (day4+day5+day6)/3,
    time ~ (day7+day8)/2,
    time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3 - (day4+day5+day6)/3,
    time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3 - (day7+day8)/2,
    time ~ (day4+day5+day6)/3 - (day7+day8)/2,
    data = model.data, normalize = FALSE))
```

And then name and make the `.lsmc` function accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I had no idea I could use contrasts like that.

Answer (score 0):

Following @aosmith's example:

```
custom.means <- as.data.frame(contrastCoefficients(
   time ~ (day1+day2+day3)/3,
   time ~ (day4+day5+day6)/3,
   time ~ (day7+day8)/2,
   data = model.data, normalize = FALSE))

colnames(custom.means) <- c("early",
  "late",
  "very late")

custom.means.lsmc <- function(...) return(custom.means)

tissue.means <- confint(lsmeans(tissue.model, custom.means ~ time | tissue)$contrasts)

library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(tissue.means, 
  aes(x = contrast, y = estimate, ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL)) +
  geom_errorbar() + facet_wrap(~ tissue, ncol = 4) + xlab("time")

print(p)
```